# Android - Arraylist Adapter using multiple arrays to fill a custom view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an app that will have an Array list adapter to populate a list view with custom views.

The categories would iterate down through all 10 categories, but the subcategories are shown based on user preference. The user gets 3-7 choices of subs for each category and the one they choose is shown. The Item is the value from the chosen subcategory.

Kind of like if the app would be sports reminders. The user would fill the category Baseball with the subcategory of their team and the Item would be then next game date.

The picture is static, but when pressed should spawn a dialog where the user can set a reminder for that item or category. (Like a reminder for the next game.) How can I receive those clicks and deal with them?

And, is it possible to fill the fields in the custom view below with item froms different arrays? I have an array of categories, and for each category an array of subcategories. The item vaules should be generated based on the values chosen in category array and sub array.

I hope this is clear...
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `ExpandableListView`

Try this for a tutorial http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html